# Changing a generator with another function - Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator, python-decorators

I want to change the behavior of the generator below so that it only yields even numbers. How can I do this?

I'm aware that there simpler, clever ways to do this. This is a contrived HR challenge, where the

The `change_generator` function that I wrote does not yield the desired output. **I can only change `change_generator`**.

I cannot change  `positive_integers_generator()` nor the for loop below.

Can I solve this with a decorator?

```
#can't change the body of this function
def positive_integers_generator():
    n = 1
    while True:
        x = yield n
        if x is not None:
            n = x
        else:
            n += 1

# can only change this function            
def change_generator(generator, n):
  for i in generator:
    if i%2 == 0:
      yield(i)



# can't change this code either
# should print 1, 2, 4, 6, 8
g = positive_integers_generator() 
for _ in range(5):
    n = next(g)
    print(n)
    change_generator(g, n)
```

Comment: I'm confused, you can't change the loop calling code, but you added the call to change_generator in the example I assume?

Comment: @RyanWidmaier: I can only change the `change_generator` function. The definition of the generator, its creation and all code inside the loop should remain unchanged. This is a HR challenge question.

Comment: What should be printed after 1,2,4 ? The loop is 5 long

Comment: @PatrickArtner: you're right, it should be 1, 2, 4, 6, 8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the built in function `filter`

```
even_numbers_generator = filter(lambda n: n % 2 == 0, positive_integers_generator())
```

Or a generator expression.

```
even_numbers_generator = (n for n in positive_integers_generator() if n % 2 == 0)
```

Or [`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) from the standard library:

```
even_numbers_generator = itertools.count(start=2, step=2)
```

But if you only can change the `change_generator` function, the "correct answer" to the challenge probably involves using [generator.send()](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator.send)

```
# can only change this function            
def change_generator(generator, n):
    if n % 2 == 0:
        generator.send(n + 1)
```

Comment: The challenge is that I can only change the `change_generator` function, not the invoking code (the for loop). These solutions are good but I cannot use them.

Comment: Ok. You are probably supposed to use `generator.send()` in this challenge. https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator.send

Comment: See my updated answer. I've added a solution that only changes teh `change_generator` function.

Comment: generator.send() for sure ... hot sure what a HR-Challenge is though - If that is Human Ressources we help him with something he should solve

Comment: Great answer... didn't figure the `send` method was so useful.  I thought for sure the `global g` had to be updated.

Comment: @PatrickArtner are HR questions usually allowed for take-home anyways? I agree with you in sentiment.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the parens on generator in your loop, and you don't seem to be printing the output of the right generator.  Updated version that works for me:

```py
def positive_integers_generator():
    n = 1
    while True:
        x = yield n
        if x is not None:
            n = x
        else:
            n += 1

def change_generator(generator):
  for i in generator:
    if i%2 == 0:
      yield i

g = positive_integers_generator()

# should print 1, 2, 4
for _ in range(5):
  n = next(change_generator(g))
  print(n)
```

Comment: You're right about parentheses. I added more context to clarify. I cannot change the content of the loop. I'm guessing that this might be solved with a decorator.

Answer (score 1):

In your very specific problem, if you can't change the `print(n)` part then you are pretty cornered because you can't change the instance of generator `g` that was created for `positive_integers_generator()`.

In what may be a frowned upon answer, in this particular case you might want to update the `global g` to be reassigned to a new `generator` after that:

```
def change_generator(generator, n):
    def even_gen():
        n = 2
        while True:
            if n % 2 == 0:
                yield n
            else:
                yield
            n += 1
    global g                          # directly change the g referenced in main code
    if not g.__name__ == 'even_gen':  # change g if it is not even_gen
        g = even_gen()

# output:
# 1
# 2
# None
# 4
# None
```