# Modifying a generator using send

Tags: python, generator

I want to modify a generator by **only changing the manipulate_generator function below**. This is a HR challenge that has had me scratching my head throughout the day. I got the idea of using send from [a previous SO question on even numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54794880/changing-a-generator-with-another-function-python-3-x). I cannot get to work using a primality checker. The algorithm should print the first 10 non-primes. It's currently printing 3.

```
from math import sqrt
from itertools import count, islice

def is_prime(n):
    if n < 2:
        return False

    for number in islice(count(2), int(sqrt(n) - 1)):
        if n % number == 0:
            return False

    return True

# this is the only portion of the code that can be changed  
def manipulate_generator(generator, n):
     if not is_prime(n):
         generator.send(n+1)


#all the code below cannot be changed 
def positive_integers_generator():
    n = 1
    while True:
        x = yield n
        if x is not None:
            n = x
        else:
            n += 1

k = int(input())
g = positive_integers_generator()
for _ in range(k):
    n = next(g)
    print(n)
    manipulate_generator(g, n)
```

Comment: I don't believe it's possible like that: `.send` always continues the generator, so you will lose the next value that is yielded. What you could do is _replace_ the generator, i.e. `g = (val for val in g if not is_prime(n))`, which you can do _before_ the loop.

Comment: @L3viathan Only the `manipulate_generator` function can be modified. Those are the restrictions of the challenge. The loop and the instantiation of the original generator cannot be changed.

Comment: How about `def manipulate_generator(generator, n): global g; g = ...`?

Comment: @L3viathan: I tried it and got stuck mid execution here: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1M8qM59ZYCTvyROk8YuTCuPGN8yJqyiCB